# JavaScript function load the page

Tags: javascript, validation

I have this function. It's a validation for register page, need to check if the date is valid.

For some reason, it call the server and load the page, 
I tried to delete some rows , thought they maybe the cause for this but didnt able to find any specific.

```
function CheckDate(sender, args) {
    var DateReg = document.getElementById("DateReg").value;
    DateReg = DateReg.split('/');
    var DateReg = date[0],
        month = date[1],
        year = date[2];
    var date = new Date();
    var CurrentYear = date.getFullYear();
    args.IsValid = true;
    if (day < 1 || day > 31 || month < 1 || month > 12 || year > CurrentYear || year < CurrentYear - 120) {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
    return args.IsValid;
}
```

DateReg:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DateReg" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
```

Validation Which calls the function:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ClientValidationFunction="CheckDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Re-check Date Field">&nbsp;</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Any suggestions?